# document level regex

Tags: regex, parsing

I am looking to create a system that extracts blocks of code from C++ files.  For example, if I wanted to extract every while loop, I would look for a pattern that begins with `while` and ends with `}`.  The problem with that specific example is that while loops may contain other scope blocks, so I'd need to:

1. Find the string `while` - regex can easily do this
2. match braces starting with the open brace after the `while` and ending with its matching brace
3. Also match while loops that contain a single line and no braces
4. Handle as many special cases as possible, such as while loops declared in comments etc, as per @Cid's suggestion

I can do this with a parser and a lot of code, but I was wondering if anything existed that perhaps extends regex to this sort of document level query?

Comment: Regex are maybe not suited for that purpose. That would be really harder than you expect. `//while {  }` <-- this is commented. `str = "}"` <-- this is a string

Comment: Yes, I fully agree (and have encountered several such instances in my test code already).  I was wondering if there is something perhaps better suited?

Comment: I should also mention that I'm looking for a solution that works for as many test cases that we can come up with, but not necessarily one that works as well as a human or a parser.   If a few examples slip through the cracks that's probably OK and will require a patch

Comment: Which language's regex are you using, some regex engines are more powerful than others.

Comment: @JGNI: I am using Python's `re` library at the moment, but I'm not tied to a particular engine at this stage of the project

Comment: You might want to switch to the regex library https://pypi.org/project/regex/ which gives you a more gamer like expressive syntax using the (?(DEFINE)) verb.

Answer (score 2):

There are parser libraries and tools, even free open-source ones.  Clang has one, for example. So does GCC. There are others.

It's a lot of code because C++ is hard to parse. But if someone else gas written the code and it works, that's nit a problem. The usual difficulty with using these products is finding good documentation, but you can always try asking specific questions here

But just doing a lexical analysis of C++ is less difficult, and would be sufficient for crude analysis of program structure if you don't care that it will fail on corner cases. If you start with preprocessed code (or make the dubious assumption that preprocessing doesn't change the program structure) and don't worry about identifying template brackets (in particular, distinguishing between the right shift operator and two consecutive close angle brackets), you should be able to build a lexical analyser with a reasonably short scanner generator specification.

That might be sufficient for crude analysis of program structure if you don't care that it will fail on corner cases.